# Indicador de atividade em SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Como faço para apresentar um indicador de atividade usando SwiftUI?

Eu tenho uma idéia vaga de como fazer isso apresentando o `UIActivityIndicatorView` do `UIKit` usando a função `.overlay(overlay: )` mas gostaria de saber se tem como fazer o mesmo usando somente SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma nova view chamada `ProgressView` foi introduzida com o iOS 14 (Xcode 12) e pode ser utilizada para indicar progresso por tempo indeterminado se não é utilizada com valores para o atual estado e o total.

O valor padrão para estilo da `ProgressView` é `CircularProgressViewStyle` e corresponde a algo bem similar ao `UIActivityIndicatorView` do `UIKit`.

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ProgressView()
           // caso queira mudar o estilo:
           // .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Mais informações [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/progressview).